# Handling CORS Issues in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an API with our API server script and am trying to communicate with the API on the IONIC framework application. I am working but it keeps on bringing up the cross-origin blocked error:

[image]

Comment: Read some of the documentation on CORs issues: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: This is an issue identified by Ionic when running in `ionic serve`. I have answered your question below, but a start would be looking at : http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When developing locally using `ionic serve` or `ionic run/emulate -l -c` with livereload enabled, ionic creates a local dev server at port 8100 by default (`http://localhost:8100/` ). The `origin` in this case is `localhost:8100` , which when you contact an external service via HTTP with CORS enabled, they deem the request not trustworthy and therefor reject it.

As suggested by Ionic themselves (http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) , you can create a proxy alias within the Ionic app to route the API calls via, avoiding the `origin` issue altogether, however, their guide was specific for Ionic 1, so here is an update for Ionic v2.

### **Creating a Proxy in Ionic v2**

Open `ionic.config.json`  and add in the following `proxies` setup.

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "app_id": "xyz-projectid",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [{
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "https://the-real-api-host.com"
  }]
}
```

In this instance, we are creating a path within the ionic app at `/api` ,which will forward requests to the endpoint `https://the-real-api-host.com` .
If you wanted to use a different api endpoint, for example `http://my-custom-api.com/api/v2/` , you could insert it into `proxyUrl` instead.

### Updating References to API Endpoint

In your app code, you now need to update all the references of the base URL for the API endpoint at `https://the-real-api-host.com`  with `/api` . A call to `/api` should be detected when in Ionic serve, and proxied to the real address.

Each projects implementation may vary. In my case, I did not have control of the API, as it was an external service, so I could not control the CORS handling/responses myself.

**Note:** remember to restart the server (`ionic serve`) or you will get 404's from your API call because it will not yet be proxying.

Comment: Hello, Do you know whether this solution works for `Ionic View`

Comment: Sorry @MichaelSmith I'm not sure, I haven't tried it with Ionic View.

Answer (score 6):

If you have no way to change the server configuration, you should use [Http native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) to perform Http requests from your mobile device, to prevent cors problems. However, in web enviroment you still need to use Angular's HtttClient. Fortunately, with [ionic-native-http-connection-backend](https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend) library you can use the same HttpClient service for both enviroments, and Http native will be used internally if the app is executed from a mobile device. It's a kind of wrapper.

Comment: Brilliant! This answer should have 100+ upvotes. O.O

Comment: I really try to use `ionic-native-http-connection-backend` , unfortunately , the documentation doesn't help me to use it, can you help me , or share me some thing helpful?

Answer (score 4):

Creating proxy only works for when you run Ionic on your browser using `ionic -serve`. CORS issue is still a problem when you run on your device, specially on iOS with WKWebView.

In those cases, you can use Cordova's native HTTP plugin.

See here for details:

https://hackernoon.com/a-practical-solution-for-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-issues-in-ionic-3-and-cordova-2112fc282664

Answer (score 1):

The issue is just during development phase ,the best way to deal with it is to install "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" extension in chrome.

Comment: I have this issue in my real device and emulator; not only in browser.

Comment: Then allow CORS from back-end woocommerce API, 
refer to my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777212/ionic-3-cors-issue/53468829#53468829

Comment: @AjayMistry allow it from server side then

Comment: @Musab can you please guide me how can i allow it from server ??

Answer (score 1):

Cors error can only be resolved from server side.
But yes for browser only we can resolved it by installing cors extension but for device can be only from server side

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that worked for me is to use ionic-native http. Follow the link to check its implementation-
https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-native-http-plugin-tutorial-with-example/