# problems with httpClient I get this error

Tags: ionic-framework

hello friends buenta late my question is the reason which restricts me the request httpClient I investigated and in the post they leave the same part of the code and I am covered for that reason[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcsOY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzucD.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would like to help you edit your post to make it a bit clearer. Can you: (1) post the code that *you* wrote that's causing your error  (2) post the link to the blog or source code you were looking at (rather than a screenshot), and (3) post your error as text, rather than as an image. Copy and paste, if need be. We can help you format it.

Comment: check this solution out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777212/ionic-3-cors-issue.