# 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy error

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am having rest api's in php and I am trying to access in ionic application but I am getting cross policy error.

this is my php headers I am setting

```
  <?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Accept,Authorization');
```

This is my ionic code from where i am calling the api

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

constructor(public http: HttpClient
  ){}
 login(body){
     return this.http.post(SERVER_URL+LOGIN,body);

  }
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myIP_ANd_Port/icrm_mobile_mar12/index.php/login_api' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Comment: use a Cors extension e.g [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Comment: It's an ionic app I am testing in mobile

Comment: have you allowed cross origin access in your API

Comment: yeah I am doing that in front of my php class

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777212/ionic-3-cors-issue) and [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/http-post-request-error-no-access-control-origin-in-ionic/106029/6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to respond to requests using the OPTIONS method in your PHP app.

Your browser or app is sending an OPTIONS request (the preflight) that is not being served.

For more info you can see this answer: [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)

Answer (score -1):

1. One way to override the CORS policy is to install an extension. It
   Adds the  Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *  header to the all the
   responses that your browser receives.
2. Another thing you can do is to specify in your request, that you
   want to bypass the CORS secure mechanism. You can do it if you use
   Fetch API by setting  the mode parameter to no-cors: Like
   `fetch('http://localhost:8080/posts', { mode: 'no-cors' });`

Answer (score -1):

You cold also use proxies using `proxy.conf.json`. You can take a look here https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server