# CORB ISSUE IN IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cross-origin-read-blocking

**i am getting Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type application/json.**

```
SyntaxError</b>: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091)
    at MapSubscriber.project (auth.service.ts:29)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at TimeoutSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at TimeoutSubscriber._next (timeout.js:132)
    at TimeoutSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
```

Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling CORS Issues in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861105/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome for testing your application then you can use [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) for bypass. And if you are testing on your phone then your app must be running on localhost:port_number rather then file://app_location. There is a plugin name ionic webview that will run your application as a website in your applicaion. You must remove Ionic WebView plugin to fix this issue in Mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

To Solve the problem of `corb` issue in ionic. In server end you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` type in the header. Furthermore please check this screenshot and make changes according to your backend platform

[image: Add]